Why are automorphisms of elliptic curves in short Weierstrass form given by scaling coordinates?
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic not equal to $2$ or $3$. In Silverman's book (Theorem III 10.1), he states that the automorphism group (over $\overline k$) of an elliptic curve over $k$ can only be $\mu_n$ where $n=2,4,6$.
The proof boils down to really exploring the Weierstrass form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. Then he claims the only possibly automorphisms must come from change of variables $x=u^2x',y=u^3y'$. How can I (easily) see that these are the only possibilities?

Just by-the-way, over $\mathbb C$, where elliptic curves' (complex) points are $\mathbb C/L$ for a lattice $L$, one proves (by the lifting property of universal coverse) that the automorphisms are linear maps of $\mathbb C$ to itself stabilizing $L$. For generic $L$, the only linear automorphisms are $\pm 1$. For lattices differing from the Gaussian integers by a dilation, the automorphisms are $\pm 1, \pm i$. For $L$ the Eisenstein integers (in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$), we get the order-six group of endomorphisms. Silverman's assertion is that we can still prove this without $\mathbb C$.

An automorphism $f$ of $C$ preserving the point at infinity $P_0$ will also preserve $\mathcal{O}_C(nP_0)$ for any $n$; in particular, it induces an automorphism of $\mathcal{O}_C(3P_0)$, which is the linear system embedding $C\hookrightarrow \Bbb P^2$ with the given Weierstrass equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. Therefore $f$ induces an automorphism of global sections $\Gamma(C,\mathcal{O}_C(3P_0)) \to \Gamma(C,\mathcal{O}_C(3P_0))$, so $f$ lifts uniquely to an automorphism of the ambient $\Bbb P^2$ that $C$ is embedded in, and such automorphisms are linear maps. (Even further, this lifting is injective: if $f$ is nontrivial, then the lift to $\Bbb P^2$ is also nontrivial, since the map induced by the global sections $\Gamma(C,\mathcal{O}_C(3P_0))$ is an embedding.)
I claim this automorphism must preserve the line $Z=0$. Since the image of $X$ in $\mathcal{O}_{C,P_0}$ has valuation $2$, the image of $Y$ has valuation $0$, and the image of $Z$ has valuation $3$, we see that $Z$ must map to some nonzero multiple of $Z$, since no other elements have valuation $3$. This gives that our automorphism lifts to a linear map which preserves $[0:1:0]$ and $Z=0$, so it's of the form $X=\alpha X+\beta Z$, $Y=\gamma X+\delta Y+\epsilon Z$.
Now I claim that this linear automorphism also preserves the group structure: the group structure is uniquely specified by the property that three collinear points add to zero in the group law, and clearly our linear automorphism preserves collinearity. Hence our automorphism must permute the three non-identity 2-torsion points, which all lie on the line $Y=0$, implying that the line $Y=0$ must also be fixed by our automorphism, so $\gamma=\epsilon=0$. Now plugging in $x\mapsto \alpha x+ \beta$, $y\mapsto \delta y$ in to our equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ should give us a scalar multiple of that equation, but that substitution gives a nonzero $x^2$ term unless $\beta=0$. So $\beta=0$ and we've shown Silverman's claim.
